# How to change the image width / height attribute of a post thumbnail?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the image width and height attribute of a single post thumbnails. Here's the HTML tag output generate by WordPress.

```
<img width="1024" height="600" src="http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/image.jpg" alt="My site" width="100%" height="" />
```

I want this `width="1024" height="600"` to become like this `width="100%" height=""` so the image is already responsive in all different window screen without doing `CSS` or `JQUERY` codes.

My codes below is not working correctly. The output is another `width="100%" height="" />` after the `src` attribute instead of replacing the `width="1024" height="600"` before the `src` attribute.

The image tag output I expected is to be like this

```
<img width="100%" src="http://www.sample.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/image.jpg" alt="My site" />
```

**PHP CODE :**

```
$attr = array( 
    'class'     => '',
    'alt'       => 'My site'
    'width'     =>  '100%',
    'height'    =>  ''
);
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full', $attr )
```

I have another way to solve this. The codes below is my second option but I also want to know how this image / height attribute change dynamically.

```
$img_url= wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );

<img width="100%" src="<?php echo $img_url[0]; ?>" alt="My site" />
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS to fix this? Adding a rule such as: .single .entry img {width: 100%; height: auto;} has worked for me in the past as a way to override the width/height Wordpress assigns to the thumbnail. (Of course, I'm guessing at the .single .entry selectors -- you'd have to use whichever selectors will target your single post images.

Comment: Yes I can do that but I want this to be fixed dynamically. Not using CSS or JQUERY

Comment: Have you tried:

if(has_post_thumbnail()) {                    
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full' );
     echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%"  />';
}

Comment: Are you sure you want to drop a 1600 pixel wide image in as a "thumbnail" anyway? Would it not be better to actually create the thumbnail at the right size?

Comment: Yes! that is my second option, but I'm I want it to solve something like replacing the array for width and height attribute.

Comment: @CD001, that is only example. actual size is less than.

Comment: Be aware that as of HTML5 the `width` and `height` attributes no [longer support percentages,](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/the-map-element.html#attr-dim-width) so CSS will probably be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can find thumbnail url & give css to that

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="img_thumb"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom image sizes when new images are uploaded:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'thumb-400', 400, 350 ); //cropped 400 pixels wide, max 350px height
    add_image_size( 'center', 550, 367, array( 'center', 'center' ) ); //center crop
    add_image_size( 'default-thumb', 600 ); // 600 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
}
```

In your template:

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumb-400'); 
$t = $thumb[0];
```

html

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo $t ?>" />
```